# VB silverlight for windows phone webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, xaml, url, browser

i am writing an application for windows phone and i am using a webbrowser
i am navigating to an image , but this image is not full screen and it seems so awfull !
is there any way , either to full the wite with user's background color , or to set a default zoom on a spesific spot ?

thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The webbrowser control is slow, a memory hog and hard to customise.

I think you shouldn't use the web browser for displaying and zooming this image.

Instead, take a look at using a canvas and image control together like in the MultiTouch sample and library - http://www.galasoft.ch/Touch/wp7/ and http://multitouch.codeplex.com/

---

If you do need to use the webbrowser, then you could try to wrap the image in an HTML page - and you could use a mixture of html, javascript and css (including dynamic javascript called from the host) - that might allow you to achieve some of the customisations you are looking for.

Comment: i have try to use multytuch but when you where zooming out too much or move the image over some level , you where to infinitive :P
because i need to finish this project , i would just thougt that webbrowser were a nice solution ;)

i thouth there would be some property like : webbrowser1.zoom , or something like that ;)

Comment: i have try to write in html but it didn't work as it was suposed to ....
It couldn't even find the image from the url :S